# jquery find not working in mozilla but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one html having one dropdown defined as below :

```
<div id="comboselected"> <span @Messages.get( "AGEUNIT")</span> 
   <select id="dropdown_age" tabindex="9">
      <option id="Years" value="Years">@Messages.get("YEARS")</option>
      <option id="Months" value="Months">@Messages.get("MONTHS")</option>
      <option id="Weeks" value="Weeks">@Messages.get("WEEKS")</option>
      <option id="Days" value="Days">@Messages.get("DAYS")</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I am setting default value as below in JavaScript file :

```
$('#comboselected').val(LABEL.YEARS));  
$("#dropdown_age option[value='Years']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

while sending to server side I am fetching value as below

```
var drp_ageUnits=$('#dropdown_age').find('option:selected').attr('value');
selected_patient.ageUnits(drp_ageUnits);
```

but value of drp_ageUnits is coming as undefined.this whole logic is working properly in chrome but now in firefox. Is Jquery also browser dependent.kindly tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo No answers worked for me . I am still searching how to make it work. I think problem is with this line $("#dropdown_age option[value='Years']").attr("selected", "selected"); in firefox

Comment: I suggest you set up a JS Fiddle then to show us exactly what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
var drp_ageUnits=$('#dropdown_age').find('option:selected').attr('value');
```

To this...

```
var drp_ageUnits=$('#dropdown_age').find(':selected').val();
```

You should use `.val()` to get the value of the selected option.

In fact, I think you can simplify this even further, like so:

```
var drp_ageUnits=$('#dropdown_age').val();
```

I believe `.val()` on a select should return the selected option anyway, so there's no need to do a `.find()`. I haven't test this one though, so try both out.

Comment: I can't use .val() because I need to show user internationalized options but value in Database and for comparison in business logic , I need English value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also do this on a change event or within your ajax request. Some place where you can grab the value after it has been set. You also need `option:selected` or just `$("#dropdown_age").val()`:
If you just have that jquery written in your script in the wrong place it won't grab the right value. 
http://jsfiddle.net/W42cY/2/

I am not sure if you are doing that

```
$(function(){
  var v = $("#dropdown_age").find("option:selected").val();
  $("#dropdown_age").on("change",function(e){
    console.log('changed');
    v = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log(v)
  });
  console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: Change function will be triggered If I am selecting anything in age unit drop down but if user doesn't want to select then by default year should be selected and sent to server side.So I think this will not work in my scenario

Comment: @user2800089 Then grab the value first. Changed for you.

Comment: @user2800089 How does internationalization have to do with `val()`? `val()` is part of the jquery library. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

`$('#dropdown_age :selected').val();` for getting selected dropdown Value and 
`$('#dropdown_age :selected').text();` for getting selected dropdown Text.

Comment: @Pranava Singh $('#dropdown_age :selected').text(); this option is giving me value of selected text not the corresponding value.I need value as 'Months','Years','Days','weeks'

Comment: Updated answer, I earlier put text() instead of val(), which is for text.

Answer (score 0):

Just `$("#dropdown_age").val()` should also work fine in your case

```
alert($("#dropdown_age").val());
```

### [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Jm4/2/)

then try

```
alert($("#dropdown_age option:selected").attr('value'));
```

### [Updated DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Jm4/3/)

Comment: I can't use .val() because I need to show user internationalized options but value in Database and for comparison in business logic , I need English value

Comment: its not working in my project :( But I am thinking JS should not be dependent on browser so why I am facing this issue